# possible values of probablity $P(A\cap B\cap C)$

Tags: probability

we know that $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac12$, $P(A|B)=P(B|C)=P(C|A)=\frac23$.
What are possible values of $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ ?

It is fairly difficult for me. It musn't be formal proof, intuition is sufficient, indeed.
My thoughts:
$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A) \cdot P(C|A\cap B) = \frac12\cdot\frac23\cdot P(C|A\cap B) = \frac13 P(A|B\cap C) $
$P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap C)=P(C\cap A)=\frac13$
However, I can't solve it.  Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look solely at $A$ for a minute.

$P(B\mid A)P(A)=P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A\mid B)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$  so, $P(B\mid A)=\frac{2}{3}$.

We also know that $P(C\mid A)=\frac{2}{3}$.

We then know that $1\geq P(B\cup C\mid A) = P(B\mid A)+P(C\mid A) - P(B\cap C\mid A)=\frac{4}{3}-P(B\cap C\mid A)\geq 0$  (*remember, inclusion-exclusion works for conditional probability statements as well*)

This implies that $P(B\cap C\mid A)\geq \frac{1}{3}$

As $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(B\cap C\mid A)P(A)$ we have $P(A\cap B\cap C)\geq \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$

Further, as $P(A\cap B\cap C)\leq P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{3}$ this gives us:

$$\frac{1}{6}\leq P(A\cap B\cap C)\leq \frac{1}{3}$$

It remains to show that both extremes are indeed possible.

Consider an experiment of rolling a standard fair six-sided die and recording the value of the faceup number.  We have $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Let $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{1,3,4\},C=\{1,4,5\}$.  We have that $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid C)=P(C\mid A)=\frac{2}{3}$ satisfying the desired hypotheses and we have $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(\{1\})=\frac{1}{6}$

Alternatively, let $A'=\{1,2,3\}, B'=\{1,2,4\}, C'=\{1,2,5\}$.  Again we have $P(A')=P(B')=P(C')=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(A'\mid B')=P(B'\mid C')=P(C'\mid A')=\frac{2}{3}$ but here instead we have $P(A'\cap B'\cap C')=P(\{1,2\})=\frac{1}{3}$.  This shows that both extremes are indeed possible.